I am trying to view rows and run queries in my heroku postgres database using the heroku pg:psql command but I always get this error
I am trying to view rows and run queries in my heroku postgres database using the heroku pg:psql command but I always get this error : --> Connecting to postgresql-tapered-69603
psql: error: connection to server at "ec2-52-45-168-55.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (52.45.168.55), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
connection to server at "ec2-52-45-168-55.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (52.45.168.55), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
▸    psql exited with code 2
I have tried using the following commands in iterm but always get an error: heroku pg:psql, heroku pg:psql DATABASE_URL

I just had to update postgresql

What did you upgrade it from and to? That will help make sure people reading this in the future understand the context and scope of your solution.

If you're on macOS and installed the psql command with Homebrew, upgrading the postgresql package may resolve the problem. I'm on postgresql@14 and running the commands below did it:
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade postgresql@14


now Im getting this error :
psql: error: connection to server at "ec2-52-45-168-55.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (52.45.168.55), port 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
SSL SYSCALL error: Connection reset by peer
connection to server at "ec2-52-45-168-55.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (52.45.168.55), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "70.158.100.168", user "mdybmwtjrfomll", database "debr7aun1sbau3", no encryption
▸    psql exited with code 2

I'm sorry I cannot reproduce the problem where psql doesn't try to encrypt the connection. Running the command with debug flag might show why:
HEROKU_DEBUG=1 heroku pg:psql

or
DEBUG='*' heroku pg:psql

Please note the the commands above expose the credentials.
